# Firebase orderByChild.StartAt() is not working

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, searchview

I'm trying to fetch data from a Firebase real-time database..

I'm using a searchView to do the query, my code is sth like this..

```
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
    Query mQuery;
    mQuery = mRootRef.orderByChild("name").startAt(newText);
    filterData(mQuery);
    return true;
}
```

filterData is a method that retrun data using FireBaseRecyclerAdapter, and it's working great

the problem is `startAt` doesn't have any effect.. it always return the whole set of data, until I set a limit using `limitToFirst()` which is not what I want !

if it help, the data is all in Arabic

any help?

**Edit**
Fortunately, I've worked it out, I was having a huge misunderstood concept,
I didn't know that `startAt` return child nodes with a value **greater than or equal** to the given value ...

so I get my exact query by intersecting `startAt` with `endAT` and it worked fine

Comment: What does your `filterData` method do? How does it retrieve the data? Don't just copy/paste more code, instead try to reduce the code to its minimum that still reproduces the problem. It's hard to say what's going on without seeing such an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (read the link, it's quite useful).

Comment: It'll probably also be useful if you share the minimal JSON (as text, no screenshots) needed to reproduce the problem. You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: I've edited the question

Comment: @OmarLabib i am having the similiar problem , this is my query can suggest me solutions this.db.list(`xxxxxxxxx/feedmaster`, ref => ref.orderByChild('negativeTimeStamp').limitToFirst(batch).startAt(lastKey,'negativeTimeStamp')).snapshotChanges();